# How can I use if equals with a variable stored in a Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm a bit new to azure pipelines and at moment I can't solve this problem.
I have a variable stored in my azure pipeline which is: ENABLE_BUILD and the value is set to YES.

On my yaml file I have set my variables like this:

```
variables:
  - group: my-var-group
  - name: enableBuild
    value: '$(ENABLE_IDB)'
  - name: buildPath
    ${{ if eq(variables['enableBuild'], 'YES') }}:
      value: 'path/build-file.jar*'
    ${{ else }}:
      value: '.'
```

Now my question is: the enableBuild is getting the right value, which is 'YES'.
But when I try to set the buildPath variable it always going to else statement, even if my ENABLE_IDB is filled with YES.

When I used echo, the enableBuild is getting the 'YES' value, and buildPath is getting '.' value. Looking on internet I was not able to identify what is wrong with my if equals statement. I'm doing this validation in the correct way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the compile vs runtime time variables, while here you're referencing the `enableBuild` variable at compile-time, the value of `enableBuild` is fetched at runtime (since it tries to access an environment variable named `ENABLE_IDB`).

What are you trying to do exactly? Is this `ENABLE_IDB` supposed to be manually set?

You could instead get it from a **parameter**:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: enableBuild
  type: string
  values:
  - YES
  - NO
```

And reference it like so:

```yaml
  - name: buildPath
    ${{ if eq(parameters.enableBuild, 'YES') }}:
      value: 'path/build-file.jar*'
    ${{ else }}:
      value: '.'
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the explanation! The problem is a bit more complex. I'm trying to solve a problem on the project Dockerfile. There is two deployments that use the same dockerfile. And one of them skips the step that build the 'path/build-file.jar*'. And this make the COPY dockerfile path/build-file.jar* step broken because since it skipped the build step don't have the path folder to do that. What i'm trying to do is creating a variable that will substitute the COPY command. If the ENABLE_IDB is YES, it will get the right folder. If not, it will use the '.' value instead.

Comment: Hm... Then I suggest you rather have 2 separate Dockerfiles then, the Dockerfile isn't quite meant to be used with conditions (plus, that defeats the image caching)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash), we can set a variable for future use with scripts.

The following is set an output variable for use in the same job. In this way, we can set the `buildPath` variable value based on the `enableBuild` value.

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
- group: my-var-group
- name: enableBuild
  value: '$(ENABLE_IDB)'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: set buildPath value
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      if ('$(enableBuild)' -eq 'YES') {
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildPath]path/build-file.jar*"
      } else {
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildPath]."
      }

- bash: |
        echo $(buildPath)
```